# content of html field out of sheet (odoo)

Tags: odoo

here is the problem:

[image]

I already tried to change the width of the field but it is not working.
How to correct this behavior automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

in side the **options** tag of `widget="html"` you can specify the css like:

```
 <field name="body_html" widget="html" options="{'style-overflow': 'hidden'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `{overflow:hidden}` on parent

Comment: could you give me more details?